# How to use SSL tunnelling on OS X to give full internet access to some applications while you are on a restricted corporate network?

Tags: vpn, torrent, tunnel

How to use SSL tunnelling on OS X to give full internet access to some applications while you are on a restrictive corporate network?

Details:

- you want to be able to access some restricted destinations and/or ports with some applications from your computer but you are on a restricted network (corporate) - Even using a Torrent client.
- you have an AWS machine running Ubuntu that you can use as a proxy (and you can SSH to this machine)
- You cannot create a full VPN because this means that you will loose access to your intranet and you do not want that.

Comment: Please be aware that doing this is a security risk, and if you are seen bypassing corporate firewalls (*especially* with torrent sites), you can get into serious trouble.

Comment: Do you have a handle on the network routing needed to choose between intranet and internet or the basics of using SSL tunneling? If you have solved one of these - it will help someone propose a workable configuration of the other. (there are three questions here - basic SSL tunneling, basic network routing, and understanding both well enough to synthesize a solution to make both work for the situation...)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local SOCKS proxy by using the dynamic port forwarding function of SSH by running `ssh` with the `-D` flag. This will tunnel all traffic of applications that use the local SOCKS proxy through SSH connection.

For example running `ssh -D1234 user@host` will open a SOCKS proxy on localhost port `1234` that you can direct your applications to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running Lion or greater, I would recommend that you create an OS X virtual machine (using VMware Fusion or Parallels Desktop) and route that through a full VPN.

Alternatively, if you have a Mac at home, you could just use VNC or some other remote desktop solution and run your applications from there.